# bash, nohup sh file launches node and node hangs up on logoff?

Tags: node.js, bash, centos, nohup

I have a bash script test.sh

```
node ~/script1.js && \
node ~/script2.js && \
node ~/script3.js
```

I launch the bash script

```
nohup ~/test.sh &
```

Then I get disconnected due to losing connection to the server. I would expect the scripts to continue as i used nohup however the node script is getting a hangup signal.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you're going to disconnect often your best bet is to use `screen` or `tmux` or similar, that way you can both disconnect and reconnect later if desired.  To do that if you're at an interactive shell you could just, say, run `screen`, then run your command (without needing the `nohup` or putting it in the background) then type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd> to detach from that screen session.  You can then exit and the screen session and command will continue.

With `screen` you could then reconnect to the session by running `screen -x` if there's only the one `screen` session, or you can give an argument to `-x` to specify which one to reattach to (you can give it a name when you start `screen` with the `-S` flag to make it easier to remember which to reconnect to).   You can see a list of currently running `screen` sessions with `screen -ls`.

`tmux` supports doing all that as well, but I'm more familiar with `screen` myself.

If you want to do it with `nohup` as your current attempt does, you'll also want to `disown` the command, which will remove that job from your current shell.  If that's the only one you could `disown -a` to `disown` all your jobs.

Comment: Trying to understand why this doesn't work. I thought nohup was supposed to catch the HANGUP sig and prevent it from reaching the script yet it seems to be ignored.

Comment: @Jegsar A suggestion is found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420594/why-process-killed-with-nohup which notes that if the command you're running tries to add its own handler for `HUP` then it will step on the handler from `nohup`, and thus you need to `disown` it so the `HUP` doesn't get to it in the first place